# Does Magento support muti threading?

Tags: php, magento

I would like to know does Magento support muti threading?
If yes, then how? If no, then can we make it to support it?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32347/

Answer (score 4):

Magento is written in PHP. PHP is not multi-threaded (out of the box other than experimentation). Therefore, Magento *itself* cannot be multi-thread aware.

If anything, Apache may be multi-threaded but that is unrelated to programming Magento.

Comment: Isn't PHP5 thread-safe?

Comment: Is there an alternative to PHP which supports multi-threading?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem so. From [this thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/237287/) on www.magentocommerce.com:

**Question:**

> What is the best configuration for the hardware

**Answer:**

> MySQL with 4 CPU’s and lots of Memory (16gb) Frontend at least 8
>   CPU’s multi threading, lots of memory

**The original questions asked are:**

> We are setting up an Magento site that will house 20000 unique
>   products and will have on average 40000 unique users visiting the
>   site. WE want to ensure this is a high availability site and have a
>   few questions.

1. Should we run MYSQL standalone or Cluster
2. Single Apache server or multiple boxes in a cluster?
3. what is the best configuration for the hardware
4. Seperate the WWW Server and DB Server?
5. Seperate Images onto another server?
6. How much RAM, CPU, HDD should we allocate?
7. if the server/line fails during a transaction, and we shift to a DR server, how do we track teh payment/transaction?

Comment: Magento itself is not multi-threaded. The processes (mysql, apache) it runs on are.

Comment: IMHO, the question is more about *does it support multi-threading*. I understand it more like being about thread-safety. If the recommended configuration is: "at least 8 CPU’s multi threading", it would seem the answer is *yes*.

Comment: So, each php interpreter running independently, unthreaded is multithreading?

Comment: No. Of course it's not. Maybe I misunderstood the question, but, I was under the impression that the main concern was about thread safety… More like *does it support multi-threading* => *Can I safely run it in a multi-threaded environment*, *Will there be issues if multiple PHP interpreters run Magento concurrently*...

Comment: Ok, I see what is important here, the interpeters having a clash would be really bad.